# How to use defopt to define a function with keyword argument with no default value

Tags: python, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, keyword-argument

Here is an example from the docs of [defopt](https://defopt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). I want all my arguments to be like keyword arguments when I use the cli. defopt is detecting `count` argument as a keyword arg since it has a default value. My question is how to make `greeting` also act like a keyword arg in the cli mode but without defining a default for it in the function.

```py
    def main(greeting, *, count=1):
        """
        Display a friendly greeting.

        :param str greeting: Greeting to display
        :param int count: Number of times to display the greeting
        """
        for _ in range(count):
            print(greeting)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        defopt.run(main)
```

Ultimately, I want to run it from cli like this.
`python main.py --greeting xyz --count 5`

Answer (score 1):

The fix is easier than expected - you can make keyword arguments without a default value if you place them after the `*` in the function signature.

Therefore, change the method to the following:

```py
def main(*, greeting, count=1):
    """
    Display a friendly greeting.

    :param str greeting: Greeting to display
    :param int count: Number of times to display the greeting
    """
    for _ in range(count):
        print(greeting)
```